# Comparação de strings em exercício!

Tags: javascript, string

Meu exercício tem como enunciado o seguinte:
Defina a função filosofoHipster que recebe como parâmetro: a profissão de uma pessoa `(string)`, nacionalidade `(string)` e o número de quilômetros que ele anda por dia `(number)`. Com esses parâmetros avalie se essa pessoa é ou não `(true / false)`, um filósofo Hipster. Tenha em mente que um filósofo Hipster é um Músico, nascido no Brasil e que gosta de andar mais de 2 quilômetros por dia.

Usei como código o seguinte:

```
function filosofoHipster(profissao, nacio, km){  
  return profissao == "Músico" && nacio == "Brasil" && km >= 2;  
}
```

Porém, o site retorna que, apesar da solução ter funcionado, um dos objetivos não foi atendido, e o motivo seria a comparação contra strings!
Existe alguma outra maneira de solucionar isso?
Valeu!

Comment: Talvez porque a sua comparação é _casesensitive_? Também tem a questão dos acentos (ignorar ou não)

Comment: No caso o site pede o acento e a maiúscula, se eu tiro ele dá que o exercício não foi solucionado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já vi essa mesma pergunta várias vezes no site, e nenhuma delas ofereceu contexto o bastante para uma boa resposta.

Acredito que essa questão queira que você declare constantes no seu código para torna-lo mais escalável, mas nos enunciados postados não tem nada disso.

O que eu sugeriria seria tentar algo do tipo:

```
const profissoes = {
  MUSICO: 'Músico',
  // outras profissões podem eventualmente serem inseridas aqui
};

const nacionalidades = {
  BRASIL: 'Brasil',
  // outras nacionalidades podem eventualmente serem inseridas aqui
}

function filosofoHipster(profissao, nacio, km){  
  return profissao == profissoes.MUSICO && nacio == nacionalidades.BRASIL && km >= 2;  
}
```

Dessa forma, se você utilizar essas mesmas constantes em todo o seu código, e por alguma razão precisar alterar o valor dessas constantes eventualmente, você poderia faze-lo alterando apenas esse trecho do código.

Comment: O pior é que o enunciado é apenas isso, nos exercícios anteriores nós não aprendemos sobre constantes ainda, por isso não utilizei!
No mais, sua resposta foi exatamente o que eles queriam! Muito obrigado.

Comment: não poderia ser por comparar apenas com `==` em vez de `===` ?

Answer (score 2):

Se você colocar o 'musico' e 'brasil' em uma var, vai resolver seu problema.

```
function filosofoHipster (profissao,nacionalidade,km){
var prof = 'Músico'
var nac = 'Brasil'
  return (profissao == prof && nacionalidade == nac) && (km > 2)

}

filosofoHipster('Músico','Brasil',3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode fazer assim:

```
function filosofoHipster(profissao, nacionalidade, km){
 return (profissao === 'Músico' && nacionalidade === 'Brasil') && (km > 2)
} 

filosofoHipster('Músico', 'Brasil', 3) // true
```